# IF AND statement excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a formula that I am working on that is supposed to pull data from another spreadsheet. I have a half working formula, but need the other half to really tie it all together. What I need it to do is look for a match between 2 cells in the same row and then provide the correct value.

For instance if(A36 = (Some value in spreadsheet column C) && A3 = (Some value in spreadsheet in column I) ) = Provide the corresponding cell in O.

Here is the formula that I have thus far:

```
=IFERROR(AND(VLOOKUP($A$36,[ime.xls]Sheet1!C:O,13,0)/100,VLOOKUP($A3,[ime.xls]Sheet1!I:O,7,0)/100),"")
```

It works when I remove the second part of the if statement looking for the A3 match, but that bit is crucial to my formula, otherwise my values will be erroneous. The sheet [ime] contains the values that I'm looking for matches in. Can anyone let me know what I am doing incorrectly? Both of those conditions must be satisfied in order for this work.

Here is a sample of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to _lookup_ a value based on two matching values on the same row?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: As suggest by Barry in his answer, an Index Match formula would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula isn't telling it what to do. The AND formula returns a boolean (true or false), so you need to combine that with an IF formula to make it do one thing or the other depending on the result of the formula.

For example:

`=IF(AND(1=1,2=2),"Both conditions were true","One or more conditions were false")` will return Both conditions were true.

`=IF(AND(1=100,2=2),"Both conditions were true","One or more conditions were false")` will return One or more conditions were false, because 1 does not equal 100.

Now you need to apply this to what you're trying to do. Something like this:

```
=IF(
    AND(
       $A$36=VLOOKUP($A$36,[ime.xls]Sheet1!C:O,13,0)/100,
       $A$3=VLOOKUP($A$3,[ime.xls]Sheet1!I:O,7,0)/100
       )
    ,VLOOKUP($A$3,[ime.xls]Sheet1!I:O,7,0)
    ,"One or more conditions were false"
)
```

Except, I'm not sure what you are actually trying to compare your lookup values to, so you'll need to edit lines 3 and 4 to perform the comparisons you are actually trying to test for.

**EDIT**

Based on the problem described with your sample data, this would be better solved with SUMIFS (or AVERAGEIFS, doesn't really matter which) than a VLOOKUP formula. Since there is only one efficiency % per machine per day, the SUM part won't actually add anything together, it is just going to return the individual numeric value that corresponds with the date/machine combo on the same row.

```
=SUMIFS([ime.xls]Sheet1!$E:$E,[ime.xls]Sheet1!$B:$B,$A3,[ime.xls]Sheet1!$A:$A,$E$1)
```

Paste this into C3 on your sheet and copy it down through the used range. It should give you what you're looking for.

Note, SUMIFS will return zeroes where there isn't a match, AVERAGEIFS will return a DIV/0 error. You can use this to your advantage to substitute missing values with something else if you want, like this:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS([ime.xls]Sheet1!$E:$E,[ime.xls]Sheet1!$B:$B,$A3,[ime.xls]Sheet1!$A:$A,$E$1),"No efficiency value logged for this date")
```

Comment: Joe, I got it to almost work with this: =IF(AND(VLOOKUP($A$36,[ime.xls]Sheet1!C:O,13,0),VLOOKUP($A4,[ime.xls]Sheet1!I:O,7,0)),VLOOKUP($A$36,[ime.xls]Sheet1!C:O,13,0),"FALSE")/100             However, it does not give me that value from the cell where both matches are made. I suspect that this has to do with my value if true section. Is there any way for me to ensure that the formula grabs the value from the exact cell where both of the matches are made?

Comment: Hi MrTheBard, you still don't have any comparisons going on inside the AND statement, you're just giving it the lookup results. I would suggest evaluating the formula (http://tinyurl.com/lyeodkh). If you replace the lookup formulas with their results, you've basically written something like this: `=IF(AND(12345,54321),54321)/100`. Without asking it to check whether or not 12345 equals something, it will just return true (at least one of the tests must return 0 or 'FALSE' for the AND to return an overall 'FALSE' result). Can you provide screenshots / sample tables of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Certainly Joe, I've added a sample table.

Comment: @MrTheBard, I've edited my answer to include a viable solution. What you are looking for could be done with lookups, or match and index, but I don't think either of those methods would be as efficient as using sumifs/averageifs.

Answer (score 0):

Generically to match in two columns and retrieve a value from a 3rd you can use an "array formula" like this

`=INDEX(C$2:C$100,MATCH(1,(A$2:A$100=E2)*(B$2:B$100=E2),0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That finds the first row where E2 matches column A and F2 matches column B and returns the value in the same row in column C - if there's no match you get #N/A.

If you want a simpler formula and don't mind using helper columns then in D2 copied down use this formula to concatenate the two search columns

`=A2&"-"&B2`

and then your search formula can be simplified to:

`=INDEX(C$2:C$100,MATCH(E2&"-"&F2,D$2:D$100,0))`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods towards what you are trying to achieve.

The first method is an using `Index` and `Match` to create an array formula like so:

Here is an example of one from  http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/07/12/check-multiple-criteria-with-excel-index-and-match/

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$10,MATCH(1,(A13=$B$2:$B$10)*(B13=$C$2:$C$10),0))
```

As mentioned on the site, it is an array formula so rather than just pressing enter when you use the formula, you need to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To break down how the formula is formatted:

```
=INDEX(a,MATCH(1,(b=c)*(d=e),0))
```

- a = The whole range with all the data in it
- b = The first criteria for the data to be filtered on
- c = The range in which the first criteria needs to be searched
- d = The second criteria for the data to be filtered on
- e = The range in which the second criteria needs to be searched

Make sure that you use `$` in the correct places as in the above example.

The second method is to use `Concatenate` to concatenate the two lookup columns together and then use a `Vlookup` to search the concatenated column.